# Finding the upper bound of a 3-variable function.(inequality)

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The question is:
$\forall x,y,z\in\Bbb R^+ \cup\{0\},\sum_{cyc}x=32$,
find the maximum value of $\sum_{cyc}x^3y$.

This question was introduced in a "elementary" book talkng about inequalities.

The reason I put quotation marks is because this book contains mostly elementary knowledge,and solve not-so-elementary questions.

The method the book provides is to evaluate $27(\sum_{cyc} x)^4-256\sum_{cyc} x^3y$ and put it into form like $Ax^2+By^2$,so the upper bound is $110592$,it is equal iff $\{x,y,z\}=\{24,8,0\}$.(and you can guess how long that thing is)

This is clearly a method that I cannot think through myself. So I was wandering if someone can share a more elementary proof,just using normal inequalities(AM-GM,Cauchy,rearrangement,Chebyshev's sum,etc.).

Comment: What is $\sum_{cyc}$?

Comment: @gt6989b $\sum_{cyc} x^3y=x^3y+y^3z+z^3x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, by AM-GM
$$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x\leq(x+z)^3y=27\left(\frac{x+z}{3}\right)^3y\leq$$
$$\leq27\left(\frac{3\cdot\frac{x+z}{3}+y}{4}\right)^4=110592.$$
The equality occurs for $x=24$, $y=8$ and $z=0$, which says that in this case we got a maximal value.

The second case is  similar.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @StAKmod You are welcome!

Comment: But how can I come up with this without knowing the answer?Do I just guess the answer and approach it?

Comment: @StAKmod It comes from an experience. But now it's very difficult to explain because you showed the answer. There is also known problem from Canadian Olimpiad: For non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x+y+z=3$ prove that $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+xyz\leq4.$ In this problem happen similar things.

Comment: Thank you.I will look up to it and try to figure something out.

Comment: @StAKmod You are welcome! You need to consider also the case $x\geq z\geq y$.

Comment: I understand that, and thanks for reminding me that.